# Clang: Copy assignment operator is getting deleted while using std::Map in libc++

Tags: android, c++, stl, clang, libc++

I am facing some build errors while building PROJ_XXX. I am making changes to migrate from gnustl lib to libc++.

#### Build errors

```
f:\office\build\droidx86\debug\proj_xxxx\test\android\objd\droidx86\clang-temp\EventPerfTrackerTests.cpp
Exit code: 0
Running: f:\androidndk.16.1.1\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe @f:\office\build\droidx86\debug\proj_xxxx\test\android\objd\droidx86\android_clang_cpp_flags.rsp -c f:\office\dev\proj_xxxx\test\android\..\EventPerfTrackerTests.cpp -o f:\office\build\droidx86\debug\proj_xxxx\test\android\objd\droidx86\clang-temp\EventPerfTrackerTests.cpp\compile.tmp
In file included from f:\office\dev\proj_xxxx\test\android\..\EventPerfTrackerTests.cpp:1:
In file included from F:/Office/dev/liblet/precomp/android\precomp.h:1:
In file included from F:/Office/Import/droidx86/debug/proj_xxxx/x-none/droidx86/inc\sharedPch/sharedPch_android.h:9:
In file included from F:/Office\Import\droidx86\debug\proj_xxxx\x-none\droidx86\inc\sharedPch\sharedPch.h:39:
In file included from F:/Office\Import\droidx86\debug\proj_xxxx\x-none\droidx86\inc\msoSTL.h:53:
f:/nugetcache\androidndk.16.1.1\sources\cxx-stl\llvm-libc++\include\map(629,15) :  error: object of type 'std::__ndk1::pair<const wchar_t *const, ::proj_xxxx::EventPerfTrackerSTEData>' cannot be assigned because its copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted
        {__nc = __v.__cc; return *this;}
              ^
f:/nugetcache\androidndk.16.1.1\sources\cxx-stl\llvm-libc++\include\__tree(1645,35) :  note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__ndk1::__value_type<const wchar_t *const, ::proj_xxxx::EventPerfTrackerSTEData>::operator=' requested here
                __cache->__value_ = *__first;
                                  ^
f:/nugetcache\androidndk.16.1.1\sources\cxx-stl\llvm-libc++\include\__tree(1575,9) :  note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__ndk1::__tree<std::__ndk1::__value_type<const wchar_t *const, ::proj_xxxx::EventPerfTrackerSTEData>, std::__ndk1::__map_value_compare<const wchar_t *const, std::__ndk1::__value_type<const wchar_t *const, ::proj_xxxx::EventPerfTrackerSTEData>, std::__ndk1::less<const wchar_t *const>, true>, std::__ndk1::allocator<std::__ndk1::__value_type<const wchar_t *const, ::proj_xxxx::EventPerfTrackerSTEData> > >::__assign_multi<std::__ndk1::__tree_const_iterator<std::__ndk1::__value_type<const wchar_t *const, ::proj_xxxx::EventPerfTrackerSTEData>, std::__ndk1::__tree_node<std::__ndk1::__value_type<const wchar_t *const, ::proj_xxxx::EventPerfTrackerSTEData>, void *> *, int> >' requested here
        __assign_multi(__t.begin(), __t.end());
        ^
f:/nugetcache\androidndk.16.1.1\sources\cxx-stl\llvm-libc++\include\map(912,21) :  note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__ndk1::__tree<std::__ndk1::__value_type<const wchar_t *const, ::proj_xxxx::EventPerfTrackerSTEData>, std::__ndk1::__map_value_compare<const wchar_t *const, std::__ndk1::__value_type<const wchar_t *const, ::proj_xxxx::EventPerfTrackerSTEData>, std::__ndk1::less<const wchar_t *const>, true>, std::__ndk1::allocator<std::__ndk1::__value_type<const wchar_t *const, ::proj_xxxx::EventPerfTrackerSTEData> > >::operator=' requested here
            __tree_ = __m.__tree_;
                    ^
f:\office\dev\proj_xxxx\test\android\..\EventPerfTrackerTests.cpp(50,27) :  note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__ndk1::map<const wchar_t *const, ::proj_xxxx::EventPerfTrackerSTEData, std::__ndk1::less<const wchar_t *const>, std::__ndk1::allocator<std::__ndk1::pair<const wchar_t *const, ::proj_xxxx::EventPerfTrackerSTEData> > >::operator=' requested here
                m_latestSTEDataReceived = dataMap;
                                        ^
f:/nugetcache\androidndk.16.1.1\sources\cxx-stl\llvm-libc++\include\Utility(325,5) :  note: copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted because 'pair<const wchar_t *const, ::proj_xxxx::EventPerfTrackerSTEData>' has a user-declared move constructor
    pair(pair&&) = default;
    ^
1 error generated.
Exit code: 1
```

Based on the error, it seems to me that there is conflict b/w move and copy assignment operator and due to which copy assignment is being marked as deleted. This is happening for the Pair class defined under limit.cpp class. I have also looked into the Pair class definition under libc++ and I could see that the copy & move assignment operator is explicitly defined so I am wondering why this is happening. I have also checked the definition of Pair class in gnustl and I could not see any significant difference that I could suspect.

#### Move & Copy Assignment operator definition:-

```
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
    pair& operator=(typename conditional<
                        is_copy_assignable<first_type>::value &&
                        is_copy_assignable<second_type>::value,
                    pair, __nat>::type const& __p)
        _NOEXCEPT_(is_nothrow_copy_assignable<first_type>::value &&
                   is_nothrow_copy_assignable<second_type>::value)
    {
        first = __p.first;
        second = __p.second;
        return *this;
    }

    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
    pair& operator=(typename conditional<
                        is_move_assignable<first_type>::value &&
                        is_move_assignable<second_type>::value,
                    pair, __nat>::type&& __p)
        _NOEXCEPT_(is_nothrow_move_assignable<first_type>::value &&
                   is_nothrow_move_assignable<second_type>::value)
    {
        first = _VSTD::forward<first_type>(__p.first);
        second = _VSTD::forward<second_type>(__p.second);
        return *this;
    }
```

#### Failing code :

```
const size_t NumDurationBuckets = 7;

struct EventPerfTrackerSTEData
{
       std::uint32_t m_timeSettingInSeconds;
       std::uint32_t m_timeActualInSeconds;
       std::uint32_t m_totalEventsInTimew;
       std::uint32_t m_maxEventDurationSeenInTime;
       std::array<uint32_t, NumDurationBuckets> m_durationBucketsEventCounts;
};
       virtual void SendData(const std::map<const wchar_t * const, EventPerfTrackerSTEData> &dataMap) noexcept override
       {
              ++m_timesSendEventCalled;
              m_latestSTEDataReceived = dataMap;
       }

       std::map<const wchar_t * const, EventPerfTrackerSTEData> m_latestSTEDataReceived;
```

I am also able to replicate the build failure scenario with my test code on my dev environment. **But the same scenario is passing and on GCC compiler and on IdeOne.**

Any help is appreciated.

NDK version:-  16r
Min SDK version: 21

Regards,

Bhupesh

Comment: on a side note, using a pointer to c-string as a map key is deeply suspicious.

Comment: In what way? Could that lead to supressing the copy assignment operator?

Comment: No. But a less-than comparison of two pointers compares addresses of strings, not the strings themselves. Furthermore comparing 2 pointers which point into different arrays is UB.

Comment: @RichardHodges The map is going to compare them via `std::less`, and that one is guaranteed to provide a total order over all pointers, unlike built-in operator `<`. Doesn't make the comparison any more meaningful, but it doesn't trigger UB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Clang compiler has a limitation with libc++ for map class. 
The copy constructors are probably deleted because the key type is a const. If the key type is const, it cannot be assigned during the copy constructor. Not sure why the error message refers to the move constructor, though.

Technically:-

```
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
    pair& operator=(typename conditional<
                        is_copy_assignable<first_type>::value &&
                        is_copy_assignable<second_type>::value,
                    pair, __nat>::type const& __p)
        _NOEXCEPT_(is_nothrow_copy_assignable<first_type>::value &&
                   is_nothrow_copy_assignable<second_type>::value)
    {
        first = __p.first;
        second = __p.second;
        return *this;
    }
```

is_copy_assignable is returning false so the pair copy operator= isn't instantiated. This is Clang specific behavior.